# Flask Schema is not using all the data passed to it

Tags: python, api, flask, schema, marshmallow

Let me backtrack a little - The problem is actually happening in initializing a Mentor using the MentorSchema we have:

```
class Mentor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mentors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_project42 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), nullable=False)
    id_user42 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    finalmark = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, server_default=0)
    totalappointments = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, server_default=0)

    def __init__(self, id_project42, id_user42, finalmark):
        self.id_project42 = id_project42
        self.id_user42 = id_user42
        self.finalmark = finalmark
        self.totalappointments = 0

class MentorSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
```

So if I have `d = { "id_project42": 101, "id_user42": 57, "finalmark": 86}`,and I attempt a `mentor_schema.dump(d)`then the id_project42 and id_user42 both disappear and I get an error telling me that:`TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'id_project42' and 'id_user42'`

The actual code we are using is here:

```
class ApiUserInit(Resource):
    def post(self, userId):
        data = Api42.userProjects(userId)    # Returns a list of dicts
        if data is None:
            return formatError('Error', 'No projects found for user')
        for d in data:
            print(d)    # prints {"id_project42": 101, "id_user42": 57, "finalmark": 86}
            mentor_schema = MentorSchema()
            newMentor, errors = mentor_schema.load(d) # Only loading the "finalmark"!!!!!!
            if errors:
                return internalServiceError()
            db.session.add(newMentor)
        db.session.commit()
        return {"status":"mentor initialization successful"}, 201
```

Please let me know if there's an issue with the way I'm using the Schema as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default, foreign keys will not be included when you call your schema’s dump method. You need to set `include_fk = True` on your schema `Meta` class:

```
class MentorSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        include_fk = True
```

More info: [marshmallow-sqlalchemy API reference](http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html?highlight=modelschema#module-marshmallow_sqlalchemy)